# GoogleMaps Utilities sample on IOS showing blank map

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am currently looking at the sample for [GoogleMapsUtilities](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils) for IOS and the map comes up as blank. The IOS Simulator has a good internet connection and the api key should work. I am not sure what else to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you enable the 'Google Maps SDK for iOS' in the developer console?

Comment: I enabled the key without any restrictions.

Comment: How about the 'Google Maps SDK for iOS', did you enable it?